# Vocabulary for payment matters

Tags: sentence-meaning, vocabulary, sentence-choice

Pardon me that I couldn't explain this succinctly as I lack of the vocabulary of the subject matter and this is the reason why I post this question.

**The scenario:**
I want to change to a lower tier service plan once my contract has expired. Today is the last day of the contract and I am eligible to switch my plan. I have made an advanced payment of 2 months which means I still have balance in my account.

I ask "if I switch my plan, will the amount be deducted from the balance in my account?" or "do I still have to make a payment for the new plan today since they are two different plans?" and "Will the existing balance be brought over to the new plan" and "can I use the remaining balance to offset the payment for the new plan?"

The customer service officer couldn't understand what I was trying to ask. I struggled with explaining what I want to ask too. It took quite a bit of attempt and with the use of long winding sentences to have both of us on the same page.

**How can I better explain it in a succinct way?**

I recall there are terms like pro-rated, offset and reimbursed for payment related matter. Is it correct to use them this way?

> **will the balance be pro-rated?** or
> **will the payment be pro-rated?** or

> **will the balance be reimbursed?** or
> **will the payment be reimbursed?**

Comment: This is it: if I switch plan*s*, will the amount be deducted from the balance in my account? If they don't understand that, they don't speak English.

Comment: @Lambie You took the words out of my mouth...

Comment: By the way, did you ask all those questions at one go? I am quite confused among the and's and or's in the original statement. Or are you trying to tell us all the ways in which you rephrased your sentence?

Comment: @Lambie This is it? Thanks! English is not my native language and I assume I didn't explain myself well enough.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh Sorry for the confusion. Yes, different ways that I have rephrased myself

Comment: @FlyingPenguin No issues. I assume the other person was not a native speaker either, since this was a pretty straight-forward statement.

Comment: Saying "I still have credit in my account" enough times and asking "what will happen to it" should prompt the customer service agent to take it into account. Original questions sound fine though.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement seems straightforward, as others in the comments have noted. Maybe one of these might be easier for the other person to understand. They aren't super succinct, but they're simple enough that they should get the job done unless the person on the other end really has trouble with English:

> I paid money for two more months of the old plan. Will this money go towards [paying for] the new plan?

> There is a balance in my account. Can I use this balance to pay for the new plan?

If both of these don't work, I would just explain things one sentence at a time, slowly:

> My account has a balance of [insert dollar amount here]. *("Okay.")*
>
> That money was for the old plan. *("Okay.")*
>
> Now I have a new plan. *("Okay.")*
>
> I don't want to pay extra money. *("Okay.")*
>
> Can I use the balance to pay for the new plan?

Now if *that* doesn't work, I'm not sure what more you could do. I guess you could send an email if the company has an email.